# Call method from abstract class in child class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have 2 abstract classes `Organism` and `Animal` and normal `Fox` class

```
class Organism {
    ...
    virtual void action() = 0;
    void escape();
};


class Animal : public Organism {
    ...
    void action() {...}
};


class Fox : public Animal {
    ...
    void action() {...}
};
```

I have an array of Organisms and method `escape()` will only be called for objects from `Fox` class (I have to define `escape()` in `Organism`) How can I call `action()` method which is defined in `Animal` in `escape()`?

This code:

```
void Organism::escape() {
    ...
    this->action();
    ...
}
```

calls `action()` which is defined in `Fox`. I can't write `this->Organism::action()`
because this method is pure virtual in Organism and `this->Animal::action();` is also wrong, I get error message:

> qualified name is not a member of class "Organism" or its base classes

Comment: `Animal::action()` without the `this->`.

Comment: @Unimportant "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object"

Comment: Do you want to call the implementation from Animal or do you want the implementation from Fox to also execute the Animal-part?

Comment: @JVApen i want to call implementation from Animal

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do this as you have your classes designed. `Organism` has no special knowledge about `Animal` nor `Fox`, and you can not treat it as one. What if you had `class Plant : public Organism {};`? What should happen when `escape()` gets invoked on a `Plant`? It's not an `Animal`, so trying to invoke `Animal::action()` makes no sense. If you need to do this then your design is flawed and you need to rethink it.

Comment: @KubaKrzyżyński : I read wrong, I thought you wanted to call `Animal::action` from `Fox::action`. I don't think what you want is possible nor good design, `Organism` is not supposed to have knowledge about it's derivates. Also, if only a `Fox` can escape, that functionality should be implemented in `Fox`, it can still use base class functionality to implement `escape`.

Comment: @cdhowie I actually have class Plant :D. `escape()` method will only be called if `Organism` is `Fox` but if I want to do like you say which is the best way, should I make `escape()` virtual and implement it in `Fox`?

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me what you're actually trying to accomplish. Your question smells very strong of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/218910).

Comment: @cdhowie In my `Organism ` class, in `escape()` method I want to use `action()` method from `Animal`. Call for `escape()` will only be made if `Organism` is a `Fox` and I don't want to call Fox's `action()` because it is different from Animal's `action()`

Comment: Then your class design is incorrect. You will need two virtual methods instead of one. But I still think (referencing the XY problem) that we're discussing Y and not X -- e.g. the approach you are taking you think will solve your problem, but there's probably a better solution. What is your *actual* problem? (Hint: It has nothing to do with calling a method in Animal from Organism.)

Comment: If escape is specific to fox, then declare it in fox, and maybe it's something a fox does when it has a chance to act, as in fox::action() {escape();}  but on the other hand, if everyone can attempt to escape, but only a fox can succeed, then it would be virtual bool organism::escape() {return false;}  bool fox::escape() override {return true;}

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you want to distinguish animal specific action implementation from other action implementations. I'd suggest to separate these two different meanings in two different member functions. Thereby, you can have a (public) `action` and a specific animal implementation, probably only used within `escape` and therefore protected:

```
class Organism {
    ...
    virtual void action() = 0;
    void escape() {
      // refer specifically to animal specific code
      animalAction();
    }

    protected:
    virtual void animalAction()=0;
};


class Animal : public Organism {
    ...
    virtual void action() {
      animalAction();
    }
    virtual void animalAction() {
      // animal specific code
    };
};


class Fox : public Animal {
    ...
    void action() {...}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly make sure that your pointer is of a `Fox` class (or its derivative), Just use the `dynamic_cast` and check the result:

```
// Organism * array[];
Fox * pFox = dynamic_cast<Fox*>(array[i]);
if(pFox != nullptr){
    pFox->escape();
}
```

The `dynamic_cast` would return a `nullptr` if the provided pointer is not a pointer to `Fox` class or one of its derivatives.